# Parsing a non-json/xml txt file in any language

Tags: parsing, microsoft-graph-api, pseudocode

I'm working on a project that requires me to parse data from a txt file.
The problem is that this isn't a JSON, XML or any other format I'm familiar with.

There's a string of text at the top of the file:

```
Pallet ID,Roll ID,Product EAN,Width MMT,Length MTR,# of Joins,Core MMT,Face in/out,Product reference,Quality level,Best before,Customer order number
```

It's followed by a long list of entries like so:

```
"00380267877718041009","00380267871804927390","8026787274115", 220,2000,0,76,0,"",,,"MAIL DD 3/12/2018"
"00380267877718041009","00380267871804972178","8026787274115", 220,2030,0,76,0,"",,,"MAIL DD 3/12/2018"
"00380267877718041009","00380267871804978965","8026787274115", 220,2000,0,76,0,"",,,"MAIL DD 3/12/2018"
```

As you might've figured out, the text between each comma at the top section corresponds to each bit of information between commas at the bottom section. The task is to parse this data to populate an excel spreadsheet via Microsoft Graph API. Populating the spreadsheet is easy, but in order to do that, I need to convert this data into a format I can work with (like JSON).

It's a language-agnostic question, so I'm merely looking for pseudocode or ideas for direction on how to solve this.

Huge thanks!

Comment: This looks like a csv file, and - if so - it should be easily converted into JSON. What other formats can you work with?

Comment: I'm sure I can work with pretty much anything as long as I recognize what it is. I've just never seen a format like this. But knowing it's a CSV is really helpful. I'll look into what I can do with it. Thanks!